# Vue.js Emit event from Service

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, vue-component

I was wondering how i can emit an event to a component from a .js file (a class that provides a file upload service). My idea is to emit four events for a progress UI element.

My service .js file is like:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

export const UploaderService = new Vue({
 methods: {
    orchestrateDataPublication() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (this.checkRequiredData()) {
                // emit 25% done
                this._getSignedUrl().then(signedUrlResponse => {
                 // emit 50% done
              this._uploadDataset(signedUrlResponse).then(uploadResponse => {
```

and so on.

This is imported inside a Vue component:

```
<script>
import {UploaderService} from '../service/uploaderService.js'
export default {
        upload () {
        this.$refs['datasetForm'].validate((valid) => {
            if (valid) {
                UploaderService.orchestrateDataPublication().then((response) => {
                    this.$emit(response.type, response.data)
                }, (err) => {
                    this.$emit(err.type, err.data)
                })
            } else {
                this.$emit('appInforms', ' -PLEASE, check all your inputs- ')
            }
        })
    }
```

here upload consumes orchestrateDataPublication as a promise, but i need somehow emit events. Is this possible?

Comment: Have a look at [event bus](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/). This basically is a seperate Vue instance from your main app on which you can emit and listen to events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `UploaderService` is itself a `Vue` instance, you could use its [`$on`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-on)-method to listen to events, and [`$emit`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit)-method to dispatch events. When the upload completes, you can use [`$off`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-off) to stop listening to progress events.

In `upload()`, setup an event listener for an event we'll call "progress", then call `UploaderService.orchestrateDataPublication()`, and stop listening to progress events in its `then` callback:

```
upload() {
  UploaderService.$on('progress', progress => console.log({ progress }));

  UploaderService.orchestrateDataPublication().then(message => {
    console.log({ message });
    UploaderService.$off('progress');
  });
}
```

In `UploaderService.orchestrateDataPublication()`, emit progress events like this:

```
this.$emit('progress', 0.75); // 75% complete
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/4qq29qk339)

Note: If your project allows ES2017, you could use `async`/`await` to mitigate your callback nesting, as shown in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zq279yjpxp?module=src/service.js).

Comment: You sir saved my life

Comment: Thanks! Is there an alternative if a component does not extend Vue, or is it simply advised to make everything a Vue components?

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using a Vue based Event Bus pattern for service events (https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/).